# "Task Manager" addon for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, performance, browser-addons, task-manager

Are there any addons for Firefox that can replicate the performance monitoring of Task Manager in Windows - seeing memory and CPU used - but for all the tabs in the current Firefox session?

I want to be able to see which tabs are taking up the most memory or hitting the CPU the hardest.

Comment: If you're having memory problems, I'd like to plug the AFOM addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11922 . Reduces memory leaks and usage.

Comment: Wow! So far it seems like magic! Firefox had 500MB+ when I installed the addon, after restart it's now at ~180. I'll have to see how it goes after being open for a few hours, but so far?? MY GOODNESS!  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[StatusbarEx](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/statusbarex/)** is a Firefox extension that will show system information on the statusbar of Firefox, such as the memory usage of system & Firefox itself, network speed, system power status, etc.

[image]

However, it doesn't work 'tab specific'. since Firefox (unlike other web browsers) is using threads instead of processes to open tabs. I doubt this is possible at all.

Comment: not available for OSX

Comment: Not available for linux

Answer (score 9):

With Firefox you can type `about:memory` and it will show you a breakdown of memory usage (might be available on older versions too). I don't know how useful this breakdown is for you. I too would like to see how much each tab and plugin has in use as far as memory and CPU goes.

Comment: Interesting info, and the two buttons help a little, but yeah... doesn't really help you narrow down what's leaking.

Answer (score 2):

[XUL Profiler](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/9954) is an awesome extension that can point out extensions and client side JS gone bananas CPU-wise. It does not work on a per-tab basis, but per-script (or so). You can normally relate those .js scripts to your tabs or extensions by hand.

It is also worth mentioning that Google Chrome has built-in a really good task manager that gives memory and CPU usage per tab, extension and plugin.

> [XUL Profiler] is a Javascript profiler. It
>   shows elapsed time in each method as a
>   graph, as well as browser canvas zones
>   redraws to help track down consuming
>   CPU chunks of code.
>
> Traces all JS calls and paint events
>   in XUL and pages context. Builds an
>   animation showing dynamically the
>   canvas zones being redrawn.

Comment: Doh! Looks cool, but will not let me install it with FF 3.6. *sigh* Hope is in the future though, as Mozilla is reportedly working on multi-process tabs, which would open new possibilities.  :)  http://mozillalinks.org/wp/2009/05/future-firefox-will-be-multiprocess/

Answer (score 2):

You can try launching Firefox, measuring its memory usage with nothing but `about:blank` open, then measuring again after loading the site you want to measure, and then taking the difference.

Apart from that, though, Firefox does not track memory usage of individual tabs, and so it can't report that information automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you want is possible, as every tab of Firefox is running in the same process. Chrome can do this because every tab has its own process.

So as long as Firefox doesn't change that (and that's a serious change), that won't be possible.

Answer (score 1):

[As of this Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/71328/task-manager-addon-for-firefox):

[StatusbarEx](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/3271/) is a Firefox extension that will show system information on statusbar of Firefox, such as the memory usage of system & Firefox itself, network speed, system power status, etc.

However, it doesn't work 'tab specific'. since Firefox (unlike other web browsers) is using threads instead of processes to open tabs. I doubt this is possible at all.

Comment: @bdolan Odd, there's an attribute link in the answer...

Comment: @Will: There wasn't before - looks like a ninja edit. Thanks anyway!