# Determine which Opera tab uses 100% CPU?

Tags: windows-7, opera, cpu-usage

Sometimes a tab gets stuck at using all CPU time it can get. I know theres a way to check which one for Chrome or Firefox -- **is there a native method and/or extension to do this in Opera?** Checking pages one by one in another browser is not a solution. Firstly, I can get the same effect selectively closing and opening tabs, secondly, my workflow includes having 25+ tabs, and when I realize that Opera slows down whole OS, it's a pain to check one-by-one. Last but not least, often it's not some flash-heavy or obviously CPU-consuming page causing it.

Comment: There's a way to check this in Firefox??? How is that? From time to time my FF uses crazy resources, and I'd LOVE to be able to tell what tab is killing it! Please tell... pretty please with sugar!

Comment: No idea how to do it in either Opera or Firefox. My problem is not consuming CPU as it's limited to one core, but the browser getting very non-responsive. My "preferred" solution is "close all". That's one of the reasons why I'm slowly switching to Google Chrome which has a task manager.

Comment: Sorry to raise hopes, apparently my statement was wrong. I thought there's a firefox plugin for that, but it seems I've been misguided by an answer to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/263605/how-to-findout-which-firefox-tab-is-using-most-cpu-or-memory (I didn't notice that the screenshot actually depicts Chrome...)

Comment: The reason you can see the tabs separately in Chrome is because it uses a separate process for every tab. Firefox and Opera do not.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that the answer is available at last! So I have no second thoughts about answering my own question ;)

To the point: development snapshot of Opera 12 [(12.00-1359)](http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/2012/04/03/hwa-updates-and-opera-cpu) introduced the `opera:cpu` tab. Opera 12 hit the virtual shelves on June 14, 2012, so problem is solved. It's not very detailed, but completely sufficient for answering my initial question. Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately does not work with new versions

Answer (score 8):

Nowadays, Opera uses the Chrome engine, so just press Shift-Esc to see the CPU usage of each tab.

Comment: Does nothing in Opera 57.0.3098.116 under Mac OS X 10.11.6 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

You can split your tabs into multiple browsers to see them separately in the task manager, then you can see how much of your memory is eaten by each instance of browser.

Comment: Sorry, but this is *so much* not answering my original question...

Answer (score 0):

Tested for MacOS 11.6 (x86_64) with Opera 79, as well as Windows 10 & Opera 79.

Activate the developer menu if necessary:
For Mac users to open developer tools, select View->Show Developer Menu. A new submenu will appear on the menu bar.
For Windows and Linux users to open developer tools, go to Menu Developer-> Developer Tools.
[ from https://help.opera.com/en/opera36/explore-advanced-features/ ]

Click Developer->"Task Manager" then sort the tabs by CPU by clicking on the column or whatever seems to be troubling your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Shift-Esc works fine on Opera as at 2021.  Brings up a "task manager" like screen showing CPU etc.  Even a button to kill the tab from there if you prefer.
[Quick snapshot...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDVIo.png)