# Firefox Task Manager

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Task Manager” addon for Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/71328/task-manager-addon-for-firefox)

Chrome has a built in task manager under "Tools" to look at the process within Chrome, extremely beneficial in locating a stuck page.   What is the similar feature in firefox?

I need to identify what is causing it to run slowly, and the addons they suggested dont work for OSX or are outdated, and Chrome's about:memory isn't recognizing FF

How to get to Task Manager:
[image: where to access task manager]

Task Manager:
[image: task manager for chrome]

Comment: I don't know if there's a built-in task manager in Firefox, but anyway you might find this question useful: [**“Task Manager” addon for Firefox?**](http://superuser.com/q/71328/138020)

Comment: I need to identify what is causing it to run slowly, and the addons they suggested dont work for OSX or are outdated, and Chrome's about:memory isn't recognizing FF

Comment: This is precisely the issue that finally persuaded me to give up on FF, after years of resisting the trend towards Chrome.

Comment: CLOSED!???   I SPECIFICALLY said for OSX, and the previous question provides answers for Windows and other addons are for older versions of FF, or do not answer the question.   This is a specific question for OSX.

Comment: @chrisFrisina, it was closed because the platform is irrelevant. The question is how to get a Task Manager for Firefox, and any extension that does this should work on all platforms because it would almost certainly be implemented with platform-independent JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: FF doesn't have a task manager because it doesn't use tasks.

Chrome is unique among web browsers in that it each tab renders its web content using its own OS [task](http://williamstallings.com/Extras/OS-Notes/h2.html). This approach relies on the fact that modern processors have a lot of extra capacity and don't get bogged down by the high overhead of spawning a lot of tasks. You can see this in action by using the OS's task manager to view all the Chrome tasks:

[image: tasks spawned by Chrome on windows]

Older browsers were designed when processors were less powerful. They tend to make less use of [concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)). And when they do use it, they rely on [threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)) which have less overhead, but also make it harder to limit the effect of errors.

For more on the design of Chrome, see the [Chrome Comic Book](http://www.google.com/googlebooks/chrome/)

Comment: any suggestion to identify rogue code/addons?

Comment: I wish I had a suggestion. If I had found a way, I would have stuck with FF.

Comment: @chris Frisina: To identify leaky add-ons, open a new tab and go to about:memory to find high memory usage and about:compartments to find ghost windows.